# Getting errors after updating Angular to version 8

Tags: node.js, angular

I have updated Angular using `ng update @angular/cli` but am now receiving errors. Below is the output of running `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.0
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 


Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    <error>
@angular-devkit/core         <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics   <error>
@schematics/angular          <error>
@schematics/update           <error>
```

I have tried to uninstall node and angular, but am still encountering the issues.

How do I revert what I did so I do not have the errors anymore, and then what is the correct way to upgrade to Angular version 8? Thank you.

Comment: `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` doesn't update angular. It uninstalls the Angular CLI.

Comment: @JBNizet Then what should i do to fix this

Comment: What are you **trying** to do?

Comment: I wanted to update Angular version to 8. Then I tried `ng update @angular/cli` command.

Comment: Don't try random things. Follow the instructions here: https://update.angular.io/. And note that you must be inside an Angular project to update it to a given Angular version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already uninstalled some packages, you may want to get back to where you were before first. So start with a clean slate.

1. In your terminal go to the angular project you are trying to update
2. Remove your node_modues

   - $ `rm -rf node_modules`
3. Reinstall your current packages based on `package-lock.json` to be at the correct state

   - $ `npm ci`
4. Now you can again view what packages need updating

   - $ `ng update`
5. Update Angular CLI and core together as per Angular's update guide

   - $ `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`